# Save html pages from Chrome in one shot

Tags: google-chrome

I want to grab pages from a website, but needs authentication to show them. I've looked for Curl, but the login form is too complex to use it with (directions and generated secure key). So I can open Chrome, right click on a link then save as, then I have my html page. But there are thousands of pages... So I'm looking for something that could do it automaticaly. A chrome extension?... I don't find any that could detect all links on a page then save html of each link (product list). Any advise?...